# Bash relative date (x days ago)

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have a date string that I am able to parse and format with the `date` command from a bash script.

But how can I determine how many days ago this date was from my script? I would like to end up with a number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do some date arithmetics:

```
DATE=01/02/2010
echo $(( ( $(date +%s) - $(date -d "$DATE" +%s) ) /(24 * 60 * 60 ) ))
```

Comment: Its worth mentioning here that the version of date on AIX doesn't have a -d option, so although the OP was asking for a Linux solution, this would not be a cross-platform solution.

Comment: On OSX the man pages say: `-d dst  Set the kernel's value for daylight saving time.`

Answer (score 12):

Use date itself as date value for date. 
Example 5 days ago:

```
date -d "`date`-5days"
```

Comment: No need to open a subshell: `date -d "-5days"` is just the same :)

Answer (score 4):

Convert your date and now into seconds since the epoch, subtract, divide by the number of seconds in a day:

```
#!/bin/bash

((a = `date -d "Wed Jan 12 02:33:22 PST 2011" +%s`))
((b = `date +%s`))
echo $(( (b-a) / (60*60*24)))
```

Comment: On a side note, you can do relative dates in `date` directly: `date --date="2011-01-13+5days"`

Comment: Neat! :) Thanks. But that is only helpful if you are aiming at a specific number of days different from a given date, not finding the difference between two given dates.

Comment: It's not necessary to do a simple assignment inside double parentheses (you wouldn't be able to have spaces around the equal sign, however). You should, however, use `$()` for command substitution instead of using backticks.